# I am trying to write out the results of a process to a text file, the issue I have is with the alignment of the columns

Tags: c++

I am sure someone somewhere has had this same issue but I have looked far and wide (including here on the stackoverflow) to find out how to properly align my columns in an output file. The following is the complete code I am using (for an event generator called Pythia 8 of which C++ is the primary language):

```
using namespace Pythia8;

int main()
{
    Pythia pythia;
    pythia.readString("Top:gg2ttbar = 1");
    pythia.init(2212, 2212, 14000.);
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("ttbar.txt");

    for (int iEvent = 0; iEvent < 1; ++iEvent)
    {
        if (!pythia.next()) continue;

        vector<double> part;
        for (int i = 0; i < pythia.event.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (pythia.event[i].status() == 91) part.push_back(i);
        }

        myfile << "N = " << part.size() << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < (int(part.size()) - 1); ++j)
        {
            myfile << left << setw(4) << int(part[j]);
            myfile << setw(4) << left << pythia.event[part[j]].name() << "     "
                   << right << pythia.event[part[j]].id() << "     "
                   << pythia.event[part[j]].px() << "     " << pythia.event[part[j]].py()
                   << "     " << pythia.event[part[j]].pz() << "     "
                   << pythia.event[part[j]].m() << "     " << pythia.event[part[j]].pT() << endl;
        }

    }

    pythia.stat();
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The issue occurs near the bottom where the loop that writes out the text file starts, as it is currently written in the above code, the first two columns are mashed together:

```
N = 665
1777pi-      -211     1.19978     0.715507     32.7878     0.13957     1.39694
1779pi+      211     -8.24173     6.07047     -31.6818     0.13957     10.2361
```

That is the first couple lines of the output (the program shows the line number where a certain particle is produced and relevant information about it like the name, mass...etc.). I cannot seem to format it so I don't have to use the inserted spaces that I put in by hand.

Comment: Just a thought, outputting to a CSV file would be tons easier and then you could open it in Excel or another such program and it will be graphically so aligned.

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to limit the intermediate programs used, this file will basically be going straight into another program for analysis. While its not really necessary to have it so aligned, it just makes it more readable so I can compare it to the output usually given by the program. More of a personal OCD kind of deal

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but I'd still write it in CSV. It might even be easier to parse in further processing, if strings are involved.

Answer (score 0):

> as it is currently written in the above code, the first two columns are mashed together

well, yes, you explicitly wrote the first two columns with no whitespace between them:

```
        myfile << left << setw(4) << int(part[j]);
        myfile << setw(4) << left << pythia.event[part[j]].name() << ...
```

If you want a general way to format this without worrying adding manual whitespace, split it into two steps:

1. create a `vector<string>` containing the columns for each line (you can just use an ostringstream to format each column individually)
2. write a function to take that vector and write it to an ostream, with spaces between.

   ```
   std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator(myfile, "    "));
   ```

   will be sufficient if you just want a fixed number of spaces between each column